# Progress Bar in the Action Bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, progress-bar, fragment

Why doesn't this work!?!? 
I've tried putting

```
getActivity().requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
```

everywhere! I've tried using the supportRequestWindowFeature. And I've also tried WindowCompat and nothing seems to work. It keeps saying put the line before you set the content. I've tried putting it in my main Activity (where the Fragments are instantiated) and then the progress bar won't even show up. Can anyone else think of what I'm doing wrong?

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getActivity().requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_camera, container, false);
        _activity = getActivity();
        prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("com.refect.thisorthat", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
        mCache = new ImageCache();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are requesting the `Window` feature but never asking the progress to show.
`activity.setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);` should do the trick

Comment: sorry, I should have added that in. Unfortunately it crashes at the requestWindowFeature though

Comment: Are you doind that inside the activity or inside the fragment? Why are you vallinh super on create iside the on create view? You should do that call inside the activity on create right after the super on create

Answer (score 0):

I think i figured it out! I was using a supportFragment (from v4) so I switched my fragment to a just a straight android.app.Fragment and now it works!